# Angular2 routerLink fragment with variable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let language of languages">
        <a [routerLink]="['#' + language]">{{language}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let language of languages">
        <a fragment="language">{{language}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

to keep the same `url` and add `#en`, `#es` or `#fr` depending on what `language` value is? I can't make it work.

Comment: Do you have each of the languages defined in a configured route? Please provide your route configuration. If not, then you may want to use optional or query parameters on the route instead of a required parameter.

Comment: I don't want to use specific routes. I wanted to do so to use `tab` with `anchors` to show different information depending on which `language` is selected. Is it the good way to do it? Should I really need to use `optional` or `queryParameters` ?

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let language of languages">
        <a [routerLink]="" fragment="language">{{language}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This works in my case.

**OR**, if that doesn't work, you can try

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let language of languages">
        <a [routerLink]="" fragment="{{language}}">{{language}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it still does not work. The url I have is: `news/create#language` for each link without any `fr`, `en` or `es` distinction. I have this object: `public languages: Array<string> = ['en', 'fr', 'es']`. Could you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I don't know how but for me sometimes it works just by adding [] to fragment. Please try [fragment].

Comment: I know this answer is too late. but hope this will be helpful if anyone need to solve issue like this. This should be work fine for this case. fragment="{{ language }}"

Answer (score 2):

```html
<a routerLink="" fragment="section-a">Section A</a>
<a routerLink="" fragment="section-b">Section B</a>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

An example at stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-section-example